# printing all the method names executed in specific packages in my application

Tags: java, web-applications

I want to print all the method names executed in my java application belonging to specific packages say (A, B, C) hopefully in the order(if not in order is also fine).

Is there a way to know at any point of execution in application, all the methods(belonging to specific packages) executed by that time in java.

[UPDATE]
PS: Stacktrace contains the list of methods in order which called the current method in execution. It doesn't print all the methods that are successfully executed. eg: if A calls B , C, D, and then E. if print stack trace in E method, it will only give me A and E not B, C, D.. i want to know if there is way to get A, B, C, D, E. I want to consider only certain packages in the list

Answer (score 0):

As I know you may only print stack trace with the method currently being executed

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
stackTrace[0].getMethodName();
```

Also, the stack trace of a current thread (since JDK 1.5) usually includes the name of the method that is being executed:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread()
  .getStackTrace();
stackTrace[1].getMethodName();
```

Comment: stacktrace contains the list of methods in order which called the current method in execution.  It doesnt print all the methods that are successfully executed. eg: if A calls B , C, D, and then E. if print stack trace in E method, it will only give me A and E not B, C, D.. i want to know if there is way to get A, B, C, D, E. I want to consider only certain packages in the list